# Zabbix - Active agents - disable warning for "Unreachable.."

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

I'm trying to roll out Zabbix to some remote Windows servers. As I can't run a Zabbix Proxy on Windows, I'm using the agent in Active mode and opening a port on my incoming connection to the Zabbix server.

The hosts are setup with the IP address of 0.0.0.0 in the Zabbix config (as there is no IP to contact them on). However, Zabbix continuously complains that the "Host is unreachable for x minutes" - it never will be reachable as I understand it.

I guess I could disable the Trigger that generates that warning, but I wanted to see if there was a "proper" way to do it with Active agents. (or is that the proper way?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the item types. If a host has passive items, Zabbix server tries to connect to that host for those items. If it has active items, incoming agent connections will attempt to serve those.

In this case, you should make sure that the "Host is unreachable for x minutes" trigger checks an active item (`Zabbix agent (active)`, not just `Zabbix agent`). Even more, you should make sure all the items, LLD rules and LLD prototypes are active agent ones, not the passive ones.

Comment: Thanks. I'd converted the "items" to active monitoring but not the prototypes etc. Annoyingly, there doesn't look to be a way to update the LLD stuff in bulk like there is with the items, but once changed, it's working as it should.

Comment: Regarding mass update for LLD rules and prototypes, vote on https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-1451 and https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-1190 .